# Oracle (+) outer join and constant values

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join

I'm running into an issue with which I can't figure out how to correctly configure a join. I'm using reporting software that utilizes the (+) indicators in the WHERE clause for our Oracle database. I have two tables:

CHECK and TRANSACTION. A check can have multiple transactions, but a transaction doesn't necessarily have a corresponding check.

Both tables have indicators identifying current records called CURRENT that is either a 'Y' or 'N'.

Join option 1:

```
Select *
FROM TXN,CHK
WHERE
TXN.CHK_ID = CHK.CHK_ID(+)
and TXN.CURRENT = 'Y'
and CHK.CURRENT = 'Y'
```

Join option 2:

```
Select *
FROM TXN,CHK
WHERE
TXN.CHK_ID = CHK.CHK_ID(+)
and TXN.CURRENT = 'Y'
and CHK.CURRENT(+) = 'Y'
```

These joins produce different results, and I can't seem to figure out what effect the extra outer join indicator is having when applied to the CHK.CURRENT field. The query with the extra indicator produces a larger result set. Can someone help explain what's going on here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm going to explain this by using equivalent "ANSI JOIN" syntax:

#### Option 1

```
SELECT *
FROM TXN
LEFT JOIN CHK 
  ON TXN.CHK_ID = CHK.CHK_ID
WHERE TXN.CURRENT = 'Y'
AND CHK.CURRENT = 'Y'
```

#### Option 2

```
SELECT *
FROM TXN
LEFT JOIN CHK 
  ON TXN.CHK_ID = CHK.CHK_ID 
  AND CHK.CURRENT = 'Y'
WHERE TXN.CURRENT = 'Y'
```

As you can see, in option 1, your constant predicates are applied *after* the `LEFT JOIN` table expression is specified, i.e. on the result of the `LEFT JOIN`.

In option 2, one of your constant predicates is part of the `LEFT JOIN` expression.

#### How does `LEFT JOIN` work?

The idea of a `LEFT JOIN` is that it will return all rows from the *LEFT* side of the `JOIN` expression, regardless if there is a matching row on the other side, given the join predicate. So, in option 2, regardless if you find a row in `CHK` with `CURRENT = 'Y'` for a row in `TXN`, the row in `TXN` is still returned. This is why you get more rows in option 2.

Also, this example should explain why you should prefer the "ANSI JOIN" syntax. From a maintenance / readability perspective, it is much more clear what your query is doing.

Answer (score 3):

.The `(+)` operator tells Oracle that a predicate is part of an outer join rather than a filter predicate that can be applied after the join.  Using the SQL 99 outer join syntax, the first query is equivalent to

```
SELECT *
  FROM txn
       left outer join chk 
         on( txn.chk_id = chk.chk_id )
 WHERE txn.current = 'Y'
   AND chk.current = 'Y'
```

while the second is equivalent to

```
SELECT *
  FROM txn
       left outer join chk 
         on( txn.chk_id  = chk.chk_id AND
             chk.current = 'Y')
 WHERE txn.current = 'Y'
```

Logically, in the first case, you do the outer join but then all the rows where `chk.current` was `NULL` get filtered out.  In the second case, the `chk.current = 'Y'` condition doesn't filter out any rows, it just controls whether a matching row is found in `chk` or whether a left outer join is performed.

Answer (score 0):

Join option 1 will consider only those rows where CHK.CURRENT = 'Y'. Therefore, if the transaction has no check, CHK.CURRENT will be NULL and the row will not be in the result set.

Join option 2 will consider those rows where CHK.CURRENT, if there was a check, is 'Y'. If the transaction has no check, this test will not be applied and the row will be in the result set.

You can see the difference with this comparison:

```
Select *
FROM TXN,CHK
WHERE
TXN.CHK_ID = CHK.CHK_ID(+)
and TXN.CURRENT = 'Y'
and CHK.CURRENT(+) = 'Y'
MINUS
Select *
FROM TXN,CHK
WHERE
TXN.CHK_ID = CHK.CHK_ID(+)
and TXN.CURRENT = 'Y'
and CHK.CURRENT = 'Y'
```

Answer (score 0):

Join option 1 is the equivalent of:

```
SELECT *
FROM   TXN
       LEFT OUTER JOIN CHK
       ON ( TXN.CHK_ID = CHK.CHK_ID )
WHERE  TXN.CURRENT = 'Y'
AND    CHK.CURRENT = 'Y'
```

However, since any rows that are in the result set will have `CHK.CURRENT = 'Y'` (a non-null value) then those rows must have matched on `CHK_ID` and the query is actually the equivalent of:

```
SELECT *
FROM   TXN
       INNER JOIN CHK
       ON ( TXN.CHK_ID = CHK.CHK_ID )
WHERE  TXN.CURRENT = 'Y'
AND    CHK.CURRENT = 'Y'
```

Join option 2 is the equivalent of:

```
SELECT *
FROM   TXN
       LEFT OUTER JOIN CHK
       ON (    TXN.CHK_ID  = CHK.CHK_ID
           AND CHK.CURRENT = 'Y' )
WHERE  TXN.CURRENT = 'Y'
```

You can make Join option 1 the equivalent of option 2 using:

```
SELECT *
FROM   TXN
       LEFT OUTER JOIN CHK
       ON ( TXN.CHK_ID = CHK.CHK_ID )
WHERE  TXN.CURRENT = 'Y'
AND    ( CHK.CURRENT = 'Y' OR CHK.CHK_ID IS NULL )
```